# Change the Dropdown width using Jquery

Tags: jquery

In my form has four DropDown list controls, I want to set width for one of the control as 200px using Jquery. Because this control's value dynamically change and dont know how length is. How to do this? with IE8.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

```
$('#selectId').width(200);
```

or [CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/cD4GL/):

```
$('#selectId').css({'width': 200});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help if you post your HTML but you can do it like this:

```
$("#idOfMyDropdown").css("width", "200px");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event to keep track when the value of your select has been changed and use **[width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)** to set the width of it:

```
$('#dropDownId').change(function() {
    $(this).width(200);
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the length of the options then you could just set `width: auto;` and let it size accordingly. But if you do need to set it to 200px though use:

```
$('your-selector').css("width", 200);
```